# Why my iOS device doesn't scan for advertising extensions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-5

I am trying to scan for advertising extensions, but them aren't discovered by scanner. I am using iPad A2152 which supports Bluetooth 5.0. Of course my device has installed iOS 13. I have written code for test if my device supports this functionality:

```
        if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
            if ([CBCentralManager supportsFeatures:CBCentralManagerFeatureExtendedScanAndConnect]) {
                NSLog(@"YES");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"NO");
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not iOS 13");
        }
```

but I don't know why I get result NO.

Has someone tried to check any device if its is supporting advertising extensions? 
Maybe something more should be added to enable its?

Comment: I get "NO" on both an iPhone 11 Pro and an iPad Pro, so either there is a bug or the feature hasn't yet been enabled in iOS 13 despite their intention to do so last year.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a phone or any hardware device supports Bluetooth 5 doesn't mean that it supports all Bluetooth 5 features. In your case, I am guessing that the hardware supports some other Bluetooth 5 feature (e.g. 2MPH) but not advertising extensions.

You can find more information in this other StackOverflow answer:-

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48269989/2215147

I hope this helps.